# How is UIViewController automatically conforming to TableView protocols?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

My project contains several view controllers which manage tables. These controllers, which don't explicitly conform to UITableViewDelegate or UITableViewDataSource, and which subclass UIViewController rather than UITableViewController, nevertheless manage to expose the table view methods I've implemented from those protocols, such as `tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat`. These view controllers are coming from storyboard, which could be doing some behind-the-scenes work I'm not aware of. How is this magic happening? Where does the implicit conformity to these protocols come from?

Answer (score 0):

You could select any class as UITableView delegate in Storyboard. Storyboard does not check does class really confirms to some protocol or not. So you will not receive a compile-time error. In runtime UITableView also does not check does it's delegate implement **protocol** or not. Instead UITableView uses [respondsToSelector](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418583-respondstoselector?language=objc) to check whether it's delegate has required **methods**. Since your view controller has - everything works fine.